Distribution of derivative of identically distributed parametrized random variables
I'm struggling with the following question: Suppose $X(\theta)$ and $Y(\theta)$ are two random variables that are identically distributed for all values of the parameter $\theta$, and also that they are both differentiable with respect to $\theta$. Their partial derivatives wrt $\theta$, $\frac{\partial X(\theta)}{\partial \theta}$ and $\frac{\partial Y(\theta)}{\partial \theta}$, are they also identically distributed to each other?
If not, is there a counter-example to this? I know that function of identically distributed random variables are also identically distributed, but the derivative with respect to $\theta$ is not a function of the outcome in the same way, so I haven't been able to adapt the proof to this setting.
Some context for anyone interested: Without going into too much detail, I seem to have encountered two parametrized stochastic processes with the same distribution but that have different distributions after differentiating with respect to a parameter $\theta$, and I'm trying to figure out if that makes sense or if I have done something wrong by looking at a simpler example.

Counter-example: Let $\{Y,Z\}$ be i.i.d., $N(0,1)$. Let $Y(\theta)=Y$ and $X(\theta)=\sin \theta \, Y+\cos \theta \, Z$. For each $\theta$, $X(\theta)$ and $Y(\theta)$ have standard normal distrbution. But $Y'(0)=0$ and  $X'(0)$ has standard normal distribution.
However, if the two processes have the same finite dimensional distributions (or, at least the same two dimensional distributions), then the derivatives will have the same distribution.

Brilliant, thanks a lot!
I think I have to review my probability theory a bit because finite dimensional distributions have faded from my memory, but that sounds like a great lead, thanks for that too.
